# Why was question about Celler family deleted?

Tags: discussion

As an American of partial Jewish ethnic heritage, like Emanuel Celler, I am personally offended that Stack Exchange deleted my answer and the corresponding [question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36247/were-emanuel-cellers-paternal-grandparents-and-maternal-grandmother-jewish/36250#36250) about this family so important to American history and Holocaust history.

Firstly, the claim was extremely notable, as it appears on Emanuel Celler's [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emanuel_Celler)

> Celler was born in Brooklyn, the son of Josephine (née Müller) and Henry H. Celler. All of his grandparents immigrated from Germany; his paternal grandparents and maternal grandmother were Jewish (his maternal grandfather was Catholic).

Secondly, my answer was based on quotes from Emanuel Celler's [autobiography](https://books.google.com/books?id=ffwOAQAAIAAJ&q=%22we%20practiced%20reform%20judaism%22%20approach&dq=%22we%20practiced%20reform%20judaism%22%20approach&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI_vKam-zQAhWB7SYKHesxAnsQ6AEIJTAB), so this is clearly information that he wanted everyone to know.

Thirdly, Emanuel Celler was an editor of [Who's who in American Jewry](https://books.google.com/books?id=uWrXAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA3&dq=%22unfortunately,%20some%22%20%22those%20of%20their%20racial%20colleagues%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjov7rY7-7QAhVM4GMKHcG0A_YQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=celler&f=false) 1926, which specifically laments "Unfortunately, some persons preferred to be omitted rather than associate their names with those of their racial colleagues".  So Celler is overwhelmingly on the record as wanting people to know this information discussed in the question.

Finally, the question presented an excellent opportunity for people to learn about Holocaust history and American history.

I would like an explanation at to why Stack Exchange is denying Manny Celler this opportunity for a new generation to learn about him and his family.

Comment: Comments here were completely off the rails. Let me kindly remind everyone that we are all here to have a good time and not to call each other out. Please let's all chill.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've removed the offensive link and reopened. I did not notice that Wikipedia made the same claim as the neo-fascist website.

This was a mistake on my part, sorry about that.